# VBA Get values from the filter function in Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel

When using the Filter function from the Edition menu in Excel 2007, little arrows shows on the bottom right of the header cells. When clicking on one, a list of every different value from that column popup with the option to select them.

[image: Filter example]

How can you get thoses values and loop throug them using VBA?

I've tried this :

```
Dim Filter As Range
For Each Filter In Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
    MsgBox (Filter.value)
Next Filter
```

But it dosen't work (it loop trough all the cells of the column). Maybe it's because the arrow is not "clicked" when running the macro. I've found the this `For Each` loop in [a post](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic/answers/634196-how-do-i-get-filter-values-vba) talking about Excel 2002.

[EDIT]

The following is not the solution that I'm looking for, as it takes far more time to execute than the native Excel way, but it is an acceptable workaround.

```
Dim values As New Collection
Dim RowCount As Long
RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim IsUnique As Boolean
For i = 2 To RowCount
    IsUnique = True
    For Each value In values
        If value = Range("A" & i).value Then
            IsUnique = False
        End If
    Next value
    If IsUnique Then
        values.Add Range("A" & i).value
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: You mean you just want a list of values without duplicates? (That's what your filter shows, right?)

Comment: Yea, the filter popup shows a list of all value without duplicates, that's what I want.

Comment: 2 good answers depending on what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835771/make-a-new-column-without-duplicates-vba

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find returns a Range object that represents the first cell where that information is found.

You can use the FindNext and FindPrevious methods to repeat the search

This example finds all cells in the range A1:A500 on worksheet one that contain the value 2 and changes it to 5.

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500") 
Set c = .Find(2, lookin:=xlValues) 
If Not c Is Nothing Then 
    firstAddress = c.Address 
    Do 
        c.Value = 5 
        Set c = .FindNext(c) 
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress 
End If 
End With
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I'm trying to do. I'm more looking for a yes/no answer with explanation.